# Usage of Cesium Geoserver Terrain Provider Plugin for a single tile of SRTM90 data

Tags: geoserver, terrain, cesium

I'm attempting to use Cesium Geoserver Terrain Provider Plugin for terrain visualization.

I downloaded one tile from http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp address such as 42_05 region. I extracted the tiff file and introduced it to my Geoserver (version 2.4.4) as a layer. From layer preview in Geoserver, I see the region where the tile belongs and it is rendered in gray tones.

I'm trying to create terrain visualization for only 42_05 region. I dont want to create image pyramid etc. Just get elevation data in 42_05 region and terrain visualization for only 42_05 region.

After reading the steps in https://github.com/kaktus40/Cesium-GeoserverTerrainProvider, I used GeoserverTerrainProvider.js and the sample initialization code.

Unfortunately, terrain visualization is not activated and when I inspect coordinates in the tile region from Cesium, height values are either 0 or very small values such as 1e-9.

Alternatives of plugin usage (I tried all of them with no positive result)

1. Translated tiff file using the translator java utility (provided by the plugin) and defined it as a layer in Geoserver and then used it in Geoserver Terrain Provider Plugin.
2. I used the original tiff file and I installed dds/bil plugin.
3. I used styled xml file with the original tiff file.

What can be the reason for the above issue I described?

Comment: If you are having trouble with the Geoserver Terrain Provider Plugin then it may also be worth looking at [Cesium Terrain Builder](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-builder).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to visualize terrain in Cesium, you should know that there is a publicly accessible Terrain Server that is built for performant visualization in Cesium.  The STK World Terrain is built from multiple terrain sources that are layered together into a single unified tileset; the CGIAR SRTM is one of the datasets that feeds into the World Terrain.

Be sure to check out the Cesium Terrain and Water Tutorial to see how to use terrain in Cesium, including the use of Terrain Lighting and Water Effects:
http://cesiumjs.org/2013/02/15/Cesium-Terrain-Tutorial/